# Select Find and replace query Mysql

Tags: mysql

How to figure out this query:

I want to find in column details where matches image.GIF with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE details LIKE '%image.GIF%'
```

Then I have other column 'title' I want to rename these entries on 'title column' where related to above query.

```
UPDATE `news`
 SET `details` = replace(details, 'image.GIF', 'new_image.GI')
```

I hope It's understandable.

Column details - in this column to find all rows with text image.gif;

Column title - to rename all things inside to new_image.gif where belonging to details column;

Comment: Couldn't you just append the where clause to the end of your update? `UPDATE \`news\`
 SET \`details\` = replace(details, 'image.GIF', 'new_image.GI') WHERE details LIKE '%image.GIF%'`

Comment: Not sure I understand about what you want to do the column named 'title' which isn't present in your examples

Comment: You don't understand me correctly sorry. I want to rename related to details column entries in column title where matches image.GIF in details column!

Comment: @Ray I've added some explanation in question!

Comment: @amarullzamarullzz  ok, so if you have a record with a detail named 'image.gif'  you want to change the title column entries to `new_image.gif` of both the title and details columns?

Comment: @Ray Yes I want to change  entries in column title which belong to query SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE details LIKE '%image.GIF%'

Comment: @amarullzamarullzz what do you want to change the field in the column title to?

Comment: @Ray whole things inside to new_image.GI.I don't know how to describe correctly.To rename in title column all things to new_image.GI which related to SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE details LIKE '%image.GIF%'

Comment: @amarullzamarullzz so the relace in the details is irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the condition into a `WHERE` clause like

```
UPDATE `news`
 SET `title` = replace(title, 'image.GIF', 'new_image.GI')
WHERE details LIKE '%image.GIF%';
```